# PHP DateTime(): Display a length of time greater than 24 hours but not as days if greater than 24 hours

Tags: php, datetime

I would like to display a length of time measured in hours, minutes and seconds where some lengths of time are greater than 24 hours. Currently I am trying this:

```
$timeLength = new DateTime();
$timeLength->setTime(25, 30);
echo $timeLength->format('H:m:i'); // 01:30:00
```

I would like it to display `25:30:00`.

I am looking preferably for an object oriented solution.

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you need to create a DateTime instance?  Looks like you already have the hours.

Comment: I simplified the problem to make it more readable. The DateTime instances are being created with large blocks of seconds. So it's really like `$timeLength->setTime(0, 0, 6534293)`.

Comment: Since you already have the second, why don't you just calculate it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you already have the length in seconds, you can just calculate it:

```php
function timeLength($sec)
{
    $s=$sec % 60;
    $m=(($sec-$s) / 60) % 60;
    $h=floor($sec / 3600);
    return $h.":".substr("0".$m,-2).":".substr("0".$s,-2);
}
echo timeLength(6534293); //outputs "1815:04:53"
```

If you really want to use `DateTime` object, here's a (kind of cheating) solution:

```php
function dtLength($sec)
{
    $t=new DateTime("@".$sec);
    $r=new DateTime("@0");
    $i=$t->diff($r);
    $h=intval($i->format("%a"))*24+intval($i->format("%H"));
    return $h.":".$i->format("%I:%S");
}
echo dtLength(6534293); //outputs "1815:04:53" too
```

If you need it OO and don't mind creating your own class, you can try

```php
class DTInterval
{
    private $sec=0;
    function __construct($s){$this->sec=$sec;}
    function formet($format)
    {
        /*$h=...,$m=...,$s=...*/
        $rst=str_replace("H",$h,$format);/*etc.etc.*/
        return $rst;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`DateTime` handles time-of-day, not time intervals. And since there's no 25 o'clock, it's the wrong thing to use. There's [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/DateInterval) though, which handles date intervals. Use it or do some manual calculation. Even with `DateInterval` though you'll have to do some calculations, since it'll break down an interval into days and hours. The most straight forward thing to do is to calculate what you need based on the seconds you already have.