# How can I convert 1:00am to 25:00 military time in DateTime

Tags: php

I found a way a while back but I forgot how do it. Does anyone know how to convert `1:00am` to `25:00` using `php` function `DateTime()` ?

Comment: I don't know of any time system where `25:00` is used. Is that a typo? Military is `00:00-23:59` (or I thought?).

Comment: Its not a typo. I saw it in php where it would show 25 for 1am...

Comment: Where did you see that? Can you post the code?

Comment: That't why I am asking on stack overflow. I used it a while ago, I forgot how to do it. It goes past 25. like 4am would 28 etc

Comment: Where does it stop, 49?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Comment: @chris85 - It stops at 69 - you change ends at that point :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think help you:

```
   function timeLength($sec)
    {
        $s=$sec % 60;
        $m=(($sec-$s) / 60) % 60;
        $h=floor($sec / 3600);
        return $h.":".substr("0".$m,-2).":".substr("0".$s,-2);
    }
    echo timeLength(6534293); //outputs "1815:04:53"
```

If you really want to use DateTime object, here's a (kind of cheating) solution:

```
function dtLength($sec)
{
    $t=new DateTime("@".$sec);
    $r=new DateTime("@0");
    $i=$t->diff($r);
    $h=intval($i->format("%a"))*24+intval($i->format("%H"));
    return $h.":".$i->format("%I:%S");
}
echo dtLength(6534293); //outputs "1815:04:53" too
```

If you need it OO and don't mind creating your own class, you can try

```
class DTInterval
{
    private $sec=0;
    function __construct($s){$this->sec=$sec;}
    function formet($format)
    {
        /*$h=...,$m=...,$s=...*/
        $rst=str_replace("H",$h,$format);/*etc.etc.*/
        return $rst;
    }
}
```

[PHP DateTime(): Display a length of time greater than 24 hours but not as days if greater than 24 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13559451/php-datetime-display-a-length-of-time-greater-than-24-hours-but-not-as-days-i)