# PHP DateTime(): Display a length of time greater than 24 hours

Tags: php

PHP DateTime(): Display a length of time greater than 24 hours.

```
$time = new DateTime();
$time->setTime(26, 30);
echo $time->format('H:m:i');
```

I would like it to display 26:30:00 `not as  02:30:00`

Comment: Please don't manipulate the solar system...

Comment: @BehradKhodayar : Yes agreed  :) !!! how can you get the format of the time greater than 24 Hours.

Comment: actually this was the question from Jrealtime plugin... Do you heard  about  ?

Comment: @prakashtank I would really hate a day longer than 24h !

Comment: suppose if the single user gets login then the visit lifetime will be started

Comment: @BehradKhodayar : Me too !!!

Comment: @rajendiren:  but it we turn back to the question. please check the link
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: `h  12-hour format of an hour with leading zeros  01 through 12`
`H  24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros  00 through 23`

Comment: so whenever user gets login time duration will start... so where as if user was logged in more than 24hr. it should suppose to show (for example 25hr) right? but showing like 1hr

Comment: You can store the dateTime at his first visit, then calculate the difference from the current dateTime to show how many hours/minutes he is logged.
http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php see first example.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13559451/php-datetime-display-a-length-of-time-greater-than-24-hours-but-not-as-days-i

Comment: possible duplicate answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is working now:

```
  function convert_seconds($seconds) 
 {
  $dt1 = new DateTime("@0");
  $dt2 = new DateTime("@$seconds");
  return $dt1->diff($dt2)->format('%a days, %h hrs, %i min and %s sec');
  }


$user=& JFactory::getuser();
$totaltime=0;

foreach ($this->data[TOTALVISITEDPAGESPERUSER] as $user):
$totaltime += $user[7];     
endforeach;

        $getres=convert_seconds($totaltime * $this->cparams->get('daemonrefresh'));?>

echo $getres;
```

Comment: but I have merged your code with mine... just to show you I have defined only my  code

Comment: this code is working now... thanks for the help @Eshan IIahi

Answer (score 2):

Please try this code

```
<?php
// convert time into seconds
function hoursToSecods($hour) { // $hour must be a string type: "HH:mm:ss"

    $parse = array();
    if (!preg_match ('#^(?<hours>[\d]{2}):(?<mins>[\d]{2}):(?<secs>[\d]{2})$#',$hour,$parse)) {
         // Throw error, exception, etc
         throw new RuntimeException ("Hour Format not valid");
    }

         return (int) $parse['hours'] * 3600 + (int) $parse['mins'] * 60 + (int) $parse['secs'];

}

// convert seconds into time
function time_from_seconds($seconds) { 
    $h = floor($seconds / 3600); 
    $m = floor(($seconds % 3600) / 60); 
    $s = $seconds - ($h * 3600) - ($m * 60); 
    return sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $h, $m, $s); 
} 


$timeinsecond = hoursToSecods("26:30:00"); 
echo time_from_seconds($timeinsecond); 

// output  26:30:00

?>
```